# DataTables API: Datatables can't sort a column of integers due to the render (which inserts a string in certain elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, datatables

It seems like the render function compromises DataTable's sorting abilities for one of my columns. This column contains what are called "corpus ranks." Corpus ranks are all integers, but for interface purposes, I wrote a render function to detect when a corpus rank exceeds the value of 4000. If so, then I have the render function  change the corpus rank entry to a string that says rare.

**This causes is it so that when someone clicks the header of the column to attempt to sort it by corpus ranks, the corpus ranks are treated like strings and not integers.** If I remove the render function then the column actually is sorted as integers and not strings.

```
                     columns.push({
              "name": $(this).data("fieldname"),
              "data": "fields."+$(this).data("fieldname"),
              /*"render": function( data, type, full, meta) {
                  if (data > 4000) {
                    return "rare";
                  } else {
                    return data;
                 }
               },*/
              "visible": $(this).data("visible"),
```

I am aware that DataTables usually sorts columns using the type of data in them... But this is a column that has both integers and strings. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to *show* the string `"rare"`, not sort with it. Look at the `type` param, it gives you the oppurtunity to return different values for different purposes:

```
render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
  if (type == 'display') {
    if (data > 4000) {
      return "rare"
    }
  }
  return data
},
```

Now `"rare"` is only shown in the table, but when the table is sorted or filtered, the original value will be used.

Comment: This worked. This seems to be one of the quicker fixes, but I would like to know what exactly 'type' is, and how I could've known about it being equal to a string value of "display."

I couldn't find this when I was looking up documentation but it's been a while, is there any leads you can give me?

Comment: @ByronSmith Well, "*Look at ...*" was some kind of hint to look at the docs yourself :) Here goes **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render** and for all `type` possibilites **https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data**

Comment: ah. Dumb me. I just google searched it and was having trouble finding information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add another column isRare ? and keep it 0 for all ranks under 4000 and 1 for all ranks above 4000 ? That should do it unless you have other constraints which don't permit you to have such a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can using this for sorting [html5-data-attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) and [columns.createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).

Below is the code as example. I created it based on your code above:

```
"data": "fields."+$(this).data("fieldname"),
"render": function( data, type, full, meta) {
              if (data > 4000) {
                return "rare";
              } else {
                return data;
              }
           },
"createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                   $(td).attr('data-order', cellData);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option I have used in the past (but probably isn't the current favored method) is to wrap the cell content in a span with a ref tag, and to add a custom sort type that compares the ref values:

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['ref-numeric-asc'] = function (a, b) {
 var x = a ? a.match(/ref=['"]*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1] : "0";
 var y = b ? b.match(/ref=['"]*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1] : "0";
 x = parseFloat(x);
 y = parseFloat(y);
 return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};
$.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['ref-numeric-desc'] = function (a, b) {
 var x = a ? a.match(/ref=['"]*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1] : "0";
 var y = b ? b.match(/ref=['"]*(-?[0-9\.]+)/)[1] : "0";
 x = parseFloat(x);
 y = parseFloat(y);
 return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

You can then specify 'ref-numeric' as the sort type for that column.